# Is there a better solution than a for loop when you have to keep track of a running balance?

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with millions of rows. It is time series data. For example:

```
dates <- c(1,2,3)
purchase_price <- c(5,2,1)
income <- c(2,2,2)
df <- data.frame(dates=dates,price=purchase_price,income=income)
```

I want to create a new column that tells me how much I spent on each day, with some rule like "if I have enough money, then buy it. Otherwise, save the money."

I am currently doing looping through each row of the dataframe, and keeping track of a running total of money. However, this takes forever with the large dataset. As far as I can tell, I can't do a vector operation because I have to keep track of this running variable.

Inside the for loop I am doing:

```
balance = balance + row$income
buy_amt = min(balance,row$price)
balance = balance - buy_amt
```

Is there any faster solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I deleted my answer which was only a hint of what to try next.  I agree there is too much interdependence to simply use `cumsum()`. Maybe someone else will drop by who has a solution.

Comment: Why do you set `balance` to zero, if the `price` is higher than the current `balance`?

Comment: try *xts* package function *apply.daily*.

Comment: @Fernando that would still be looping over every row here.

Comment: It should be `buy_amout = row$price * (balance >= row$price)`

Answer (score 5):

As Paul points out, some iteration is necessary.  You have a dependency between one instance and a previous point.

However, the dependency only occurs whenever a purchase is made  (*read: you only need to recalculate the balance when..*). Therefore, you can iterate in "batches"

Try the following does exactly that by identifying which is the next row where there is sufficient balance to make a purchase.  It then handles all the previous rows in a single call, and then proceeds from that point.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)

## Initial Balance
b.init <- 2

setattr(DT, "Starting Balance", b.init)

## Raw balance for the day, regardless of purchase
DT[, balance := b.init + cumsum(income)]
DT[, buying  := FALSE]

## Set N, to not have to call nrow(DT) several times
N   <- nrow(DT)

## Initialize
ind <- seq(1:N)

# Identify where the next purchase is
while(length(buys <- DT[ind, ind[which(price <= balance)]]) && min(ind) < N) {
  next.buy <- buys[[1L]] # only grab the first one
  if (next.buy > ind[[1L]]) {
    not.buys <- ind[1L]:(next.buy-1L)
    DT[not.buys, buying := FALSE]
  }
  DT[next.buy, `:=`(buying  = TRUE
                  , balance = (balance - price)
                  ) ]

  # If there are still subsequent rows after 'next.buy', recalculate the balance
  ind <- (next.buy+1) : N
#  if (N > ind[[1]]) {  ## So that
    DT[ind, balance := cumsum(income) + DT[["balance"]][[ ind[[1]]-1L]] ]
#  }
}
# Final row needs to be outside of while-loop, or else will buy that same item multiple times
if (DT[N, !buying && (balance > price)])
  DT[N, `:=`(buying  = TRUE, balance = (balance - price)) ]
```

#### RESULTS:

```
## Show output
{
  print(DT)
  cat("Starting Balance was", attr(DT, "Starting Balance"), "\n")
}


## Starting with 3: 
   dates price income balance buying
1:     1     5      2       0   TRUE
2:     2     2      2       0   TRUE
3:     3     3      2       2  FALSE
4:     4     5      2       4  FALSE
5:     5     2      2       4   TRUE
6:     6     1      2       5   TRUE
Starting Balance was 3

## Starting with 2: 
   dates price income balance buying
1:     1     5      2       4  FALSE
2:     2     2      2       4   TRUE
3:     3     3      2       3   TRUE
4:     4     5      2       0   TRUE
5:     5     2      2       0   TRUE
6:     6     1      2       1   TRUE
Starting Balance was 2


# I modified your original data slightly, for testing
df <- rbind(df, df)
df$dates <- seq_along(df$dates)
df[["price"]][[3]] <- 3
```

Answer (score 4):

For problems that are easily expressed in terms of loops, I'm becoming increasingly convinced that Rcpp is the right solution. It's relatively [easy to pick up](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) and you can express loop-y algorithms very naturally.

Here's a solution to your problem using Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List purchaseWhenPossible(NumericVector date, NumericVector income, 
                          NumericVector price, double init_balance = 0) {  
  int n = date.length();
  NumericVector balance(n);
  LogicalVector buy(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    balance[i] = ((i == 0) ? init_balance : balance[i - 1]) + income;

    // Buy it if you can afford it
    if (balance[i] >= price[i]) {
      buy[i] = true;
      balance[i] -= price[i];
    } else {
      buy[i] = false;
    }

  }

  return List::create(_["buy"] = buy, _["balance"] = balance);
}

/*** R

# Copying input data from Ricardo
df <- data.frame(
  dates = 1:6,
  income = rep(2, 6),
  price = c(5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1)
)

out <- purchaseWhenPossible(df$dates, df$income, df$price, 3)
df$balance <- out$balance
df$buy <- out$buy

*/
```

To run it, save it into a file called `purchase.cpp`, then run `Rcpp::sourceCpp("purchase.cpp")`

It will be very fast, because C++ is so fast, but I didn't do any formal benchmarking.